# Cannot open backup device Operating system error 1392

Tags: sql-server

Recently I've been getting this error intermittently when a maintenance plan is run.

Googling this I thought it might be anti-virus related, however it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

On investigating further Operating system error 1392 implies some corruption on the hard dive.

Discussing this with our infrastructure team, they alerted me that one of the disks was faulty, and following the replacement of the disk, and running of chkdsk the problem was resolved.

Comment: Well that's quite informative! Please mark it as solution to a problem.